# Package installation with conditions

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, installation, packaging

I have a package (Joomla! 3x) that contains 2 plugins and it install/update and uninstall correctly. But now, I need to refine the installation/update process.

Scenario on **fresh installation**:

If Joomla version = X install plugin A and Plugin B

If Joomla version = Y **install plugin A only**

Scenario on **update**:

If Joomla version = X update plugin A and Plugin B

If Joomla version = Y **update plugin A and UNINSTALL Plugin B**, if installed

Probably need a script file, but I don't know how to force the install/uninstall of a specific plugin inside the script file.
Appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Personally, I'd simply create 2 separate packages, one with the 2 plugins, and one without.

Comment: @Lodder Thank you. Indeed already thought about it, but, as they are for the same major version, I really need them bundled together (install 1 or 2 plugins according to minor version). I cannot have 2 separate packages :(

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the plugins for for exactly, and seeing as you can't have 2 separate packages, I'd suggest still using 1 package, install both plugins, but add a conditional statement in your plugins files, like so:

```
public function onYourEvent()
{
    // If Joomla version is greater than 3.5
    if (version_compare(JVERSION, '3.5', '>'))
    {
        // run your plugin code
    }
    else
    {
        // else do nothing and just return
        return;
    }
}
```